# Display HTML Formatted String

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-arrayadapter

I need an example of how to display the strings that I have marked up with simple html into a TextView. I have found "Spanned fromHtml(String source)", but I don't know how to plug it into my java code.

Here is my Java:

```
package com.SorenWinslow.TriumphHistory;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class TriumphHistory extends ListActivity {
    String[] HistoryList;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
        HistoryList = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.history);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this,R.layout.historylistlayout,HistoryList);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

Here is a sample of history:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string-array name="history">
<item><b>1883</b><br/>Some stuff happened</item>
<item><b>1884</b><br/>Some more stuff happened <i>before</i> the other stuff
</item>
<resources>
```

Here is my historylistlayout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:background="#000050"
    android:layout_marginTop="5px"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:padding="3px" 
    android:textSize="8pt" android:layout_gravity="top|left"/>
```

And here is my main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:background="#000080" 
    android:isScrollContainer="true" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay">

  <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:clickable="true" 
    android:dividerHeight="1px"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 13):

I was trying to do something of the same nature and found out that my html along with CSS was not getting formatted correctly so I took the string and loaded it into a webview like this:

```
 WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.MyWebview);
 String summary = "<html><body>You scored <b>192</b> points.</body></html>";
 webview.loadData(summary, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

and it recognized all the styles and formatted the html correctly.  More from the android reference [HERE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)

Answer (score 12):

Use the function you mentioned to return a spanned and then set the text of your textview using the toString of the returned Spanned object like so to achieve formatted text:

```
Spanned marked_up = Html.fromHtml(yourTextWithHTML);
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1)).setText(marked_up.toString());
```

This will work where yourTextWithHTML is any of the Strings within the item tags you posted.
eg `"<b>1883</b><br/>Some stuff happened"`

Comment: This works if you're inflating a String resource, but not if you're inflating a String array. String arrays will remove HTML formatting.

Answer (score 8):

```
    Spanned spannedContent = Html.fromHtml(htmlString);
    textView.setText(spannedContent, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems easiest actually (from [HTML in string resource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667319)):

```
mTextView.setText(getText(R.string.my_styled_text));
```

This works for strings that have HTML inside.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, and solved it by using

```
    CharSequence[] HistoryList = getResources().getTextArray(R.array.history);
```

The above code returns styled text array associated with resource. It will return CharSequence[]

Then just use the elemens in

```
   setText(HistoryList[index]);
```