# HTML in string resource?

Tags: android

I know I can put escaped HTML tags in string resources. However, looking at the source code for the Contacts application I can see that they have a way of not having to encode the HTML. Quote from the Contacts application [strings.xml](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Contacts.git;a=blob;f=res/values/strings.xml;h=e37c1182741baf957fa47c3b2fc345be86b659c1;hb=HEAD):

```
<string name="contactsSyncPlug"><font fgcolor="#ffffffff">Sync your Google contacts!</font> 
\nAfter syncing to your phone, your contacts will be available to you wherever you go.</string>
```

Unfortunately, when I try something similar (like `Hello, <b>World</b>!`), `getString()` returns the string without the tags (I can see that in `logcat`). Why is that? How can I get the original string, with tags and everything? How is the Contacts application doing it?

Comment: Proper solution : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#StylingWithHTML

Answer (score 104, accepted):

It seems `getString()` does just that -- gets a **string**. To use this, you have to use `getText()` (and no more `Html.fromHtml()`), i.e.:

```
mTextView.setText(getText(R.string.my_styled_text));
```

However, it seems the `android:text` property does just the same thing, and the following is equivalent:

```
<TextView android:text="@string/my_styled_text" />
```

And in `strings.xml`:

```
<string name="my_styled_text">Hello, <b>World</b>!</string>
```

Comment: note getString() returns CharSequence, not a usual String. so if html tags are used, then CharSequence also includes info about them, and thus mTextView.setText(getText(R.string.my_styled_text)) works as expected.

Comment: Please note that only supported tags are <b>, <i>, <u> : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html

Comment: and instead of <br/> you can use /n

Comment: @pawegio surely you mean `\n`?

Comment: This doesn't work for anything besides the three HTML tags listed above, so this doesn't answer the question really at all

Comment: @Snicolas: it does support more than the 3 tags mentioned in the documentation: it supports <b>, <i>, <u>, <big>, <small>, <sup>, <sub>, <strike>, <li>, <marquee>, <a>, <font> and <annotation> (see https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/android-4.2.2_r1/core/java/android/content/res/StringBlock.java#L161)

Comment: This works great, but just something that set me back for a while - if using Eclipse, these tags may not display properly in the visual layout editor. (They will display when running on a device or emulator.)

Comment: Unfortunatly using this method, variables in string are not allowed

Comment: <font> is supported at api23, but api10 is not.

Comment: Works for me. Thanks!

Comment: Check the link for  detailed explanation about the above method.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45647928/what-is-the-difference-between-getstring-and-gettext.

Comment: Seems the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#StylingWithHTML) have been updated since last activity here, but the documented tags still don't seem to align with the [StringBlock.java](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/android-4.2.2_r1/core/java/android/content/res/StringBlock.java#L161) code. Can anyone clarify?

Comment: this answer is gold should really be the accepted one

Answer (score 226):

You can also surround your html in a `CDATA` block as well and `getString()` will return your actual HTML. Like such:

```
<string name="foo"><![CDATA[Foo Bar <a href="foo?id=%s">baz</a> is cool]]></string>
```

Now when you perform a `getString(R.string.foo)` the string will be HTML. If you need to render the HTML (with the link as shown) via a clickable `TextView` you'd need to perform a `Html.fromHtml(...)` call to get the spannable text.

Comment: No, you should definitely see Felix's answer. CDATA is not necessary.

Comment: @MarcoW. Felix's answer is true but using CDATA helps us to not to worry about html tags. This answer should be correct answer.

Comment: If you have links in the string, don't forget to add textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

Comment: I had to use `\"` for `style` property, though. Example `<a style=\"...\">link</a>`

Comment: CDATA gives you a lot more flexibility when styling strings with HTML tags. I would agree that is the way to go 100%!

Comment: `TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textHolder);
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.foo)));
tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());`

Comment: Also, `getText()` doesn't accept format arguments. If you have something other than a static string you must use `getString()` + `Html`.

Comment: Use this ink : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#StylingWithHTML

Answer (score 62):

The best solution is to use resources in a way:

```
<string name="htmlsource"><![CDATA[<p>Adults are spotted gold and black on the crown, back and wings. Their face and neck are black with a white border; they have a black breast and a dark rump. The legs are black.</p><p>It is similar to two other golden plovers, Eurasian and Pacific. <h1>The American Golden Plover</h1> is smaller, slimmer and relatively longer-legged than Eurasian Golden Plover (<i>Pluvialis apricaria</i>) which also has white axillary (armpit) feathers. It is more similar to Pacific Golden Plover (<i>Pluvialis fulva</i>) with which it was once <b>considered</b> conspecific under the name \"Lesser Golden Plover\". The Pacific Golden Plover is slimmer than the American species, has a shorter primary projection, and longer legs, and is usually yellower on the back.</p><p>These birds forage for food on tundra, fields, beaches and tidal flats, usually by sight. They eat insects and crustaceans, also berries.</p>]]></string>
```

and than display it with:

```
Spanned sp = Html.fromHtml( getString(R.string.htmlsource));
tv.setText(sp);
```

Try to use that resource without `<![CDATA[ ]]>` and with `tv.setText(getText(R.string.htmlsource));` and you will see the difference.

Comment: Thank you for this answer this really helped me

Comment: Even with a very large and complex HTML file?

Comment: Does this support <font> tag?

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question but it seems the most efficient answer has not been proposed yet.

Just use `HTML-escaped` characters so it won't get processed by `getString` but it will be processed by `HtmlCompat.fromHtml` (or the older `Html.fromHtml`).

This also supports more tags like HTML links etc., not only formatting like `getString` method.

For example something like this should work:

```
<string name="html_message">Hello &lt;b>World&lt;/b>.</string>

val text = getString(R.string.html_message)
val result = HtmlCompact.fromHtml(text, HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)
```

In your case you replace `<` with `&lt;` like this:

```
<string name="contactsSyncPlug">&lt;font fgcolor="#ffffffff">Sync your Google contacts!&lt;/font> \nAfter syncing to your phone, your contacts will be available to you wherever you go.</string>
```

Comment: This has the benefit of working without hassles with string parameters.

Answer (score 0):

it works for me without CDATA block.

```
<string name="menu_item_purchase" translatable="false"><font color="red">P</font><font color="orange">r</font><font color="yellow">e</font><font color="green">m</font><font color="white">i</font><font color="blue">u</font><font color="purple">m</font></string>`enter code here`
```

I use it in layout.

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/nav_premium"
    android:icon="@drawable/coins"
    android:title="@string/menu_item_purchase"
    />
```

Answer (score -2):

Idea: put the HTML in JSON-formatted files and store them in /res/raw. (JSON is less picky)

Store the data records like this in an array object:

```
[
    {
        "Field1": "String data",
        "Field2": 12345,
        "Field3": "more Strings",
        "Field4": true
    },
    {
        "Field1": "String data",
        "Field2": 12345,
        "Field3": "more Strings",
        "Field4": true
    },
    {
        "Field1": "String data",
        "Field2": 12345,
        "Field3": "more Strings",
        "Field4": true
    }
]
```

To read the data in your app :

```
private ArrayList<Data> getData(String filename) {
    ArrayList<Data> dataArray = new ArrayList<Data>();

    try {
        int id = getResources().getIdentifier(filename, "raw", getPackageName());
        InputStream input = getResources().openRawResource(id);
        int size = input.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        input.read(buffer);
        String text = new String(buffer);

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Type dataType = new TypeToken<List<Map<String, Object>>>() {}.getType();
        List<Map<String, Object>> natural = gson.fromJson(text, dataType);

        // now cycle through each object and gather the data from each field
        for(Map<String, Object> json : natural) {
            final Data ad = new Data(json.get("Field1"), json.get("Field2"),  json.get("Field3"), json.get("Field4"));
            dataArray.add(ad);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return dataArray;
}
```

Finally, the `Data` class is just a container of public variables for easy access...

```
public class Data {

    public String string;
    public Integer number;
    public String somestring;
    public Integer site;
    public boolean logical;


    public Data(String string, Integer number, String somestring, boolean logical)
    {
        this.string = string;
        this.number = number;
        this.somestring = somestring;
        this.logical = logical;
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems a bit over-engineered, why not saving it in html instead of json?