# How to align email text to the right in android app for sending email

Tags: java, android

I have gone through several tutorials for sending formatted text in email in android app. But there is no way to format the text with  tag.

I am working with div tags as I came to know that div tag is supported for sending email. But, how can I align text right in an email using div tag. When I am using float:right property in string.xml file in a string resource its giving error.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

I am just giving a small sample of code that I am using.

```
 <string name="email_text"> &lt;div width="200px"> 
        &lt;div float="left" width="100px">Test &lt;/div>
        &lt;div float="right" width="50px">Test &lt;/div>
        &lt;/div>
    </string>
```

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8065410/1514026. It might help.

Comment: I need to align text right, and <div> tag works like <p> tag, so I need a solution for this.

Comment: `<div align="right"></div>`?

Comment: Not working :( Already tried!!

Comment: May be a syntax error. What about `<div style="float:right !important;">`?

Comment: If any body has an alternative through which I can align text right, then please help, and above solution given in comment is not working.