# How to add a long text with many paragraphs in string.xml in android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-activity

When I added many paragraphs between

```
<string name="bbb"> ...... </string>
```

it showed me following error.

```
[2014-12-22 14:54:55 - Inspiration] Her father rescued her from the heartless husband  and she was back her to the 
[2014-12-22 14:54:55 - Inspiration] G:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\workspace\Inspiration\res\layout\activity_women.xml:11: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/Women1').
```

Comment: can you mention us the whole string or paragraph over here???

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
 <string name="Your string name" > This is your string.

       This is the second line of your string.\n\n Third line of your string.</string>
```

This will result in the following on your TextView:

```
This is your string.

This is the second line of your string.

Third line of your string.
```

Comment: Apostrophe not preceded by \ (in GREATNESS IS TURNING A FAILURE INTO A SUCCESS.    I'm getting this error

Answer (score 2):

You can add the long string to /res/values/strings.xml, as it appears you've done.

You can separate paragraphs with the `\n`.

You will need to use Unicode codes for special characters like backslash, etc.. See `this answer`.

Yes, was just going to add what's in the other answer: The other trick is to use the CDATA trick:

```
<![CDATA[Foo Bar <a href="foo?id=%s">baz</a> is cool]]>
```

See [this answer for more on that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667319/html-in-string-resource).

Comment: \n\n will make line gap between characters. Works in my app.

Comment: I'm also not certain from the error, if you're correctly referencing the string resource to begin with. Put a single line in it with no special characters as a test to see if you're even getting the string back for starters.

Comment: string tag is working when i gave around one para or more. then when i added more, i got the error