# Changing font color of items in xml string-array

Tags: android, xml, android-popupwindow

I am trying to display a spinner inside a pop up window. And I want a portion of the text of each drop down item to be green. More specifically, an option would look like :
"Transaction Type: Pay Cash, Meet Up". And I want the words "Transaction Type" to be in green and the rest of the words to be in black.
I tried the font color attribute, but that is not working.

Code for string-array xml file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <string-array name="payment_list">
    <item><font color="#00ff00">Transaction Type: </font>Pay Cash, Meet Up</item>
    <item><font color="#00ff00">Transaction Type: </font>Credit Card, Meet Up</item>
    <item><font color="#00ff00">Transaction Type: </font>Credit Card, Ship to Me</item>
</string-array>
```

Code for the pop up window:

```
final Button makeoffer = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.make_offer);
    makeoffer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.offer_popup, null);
            final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            EditText mEditText = (EditText) popupView.findViewById(R.id.payment_field);
            popupView.clearFocus();
            mEditText.requestFocus();
            popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
            popupWindow.update();

            final Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) popupView.findViewById(R.id.transaction_spinner);
            spinner1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(getActivity(), R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,getActivity().getResources().getTextArray(R.array.payment_list)));

            Button btnDismiss = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.cancel2);
            btnDismiss.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    popupWindow.dismiss();
                }
            });
            popupWindow.showAtLocation(popupView, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 0, 0);
        }
    });
```

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667319/html-in-string-resource) should help you.

Comment: @SirGregg I added the CDATA block, but how do I get it to actually render the html attributes in the spinner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else reading this: Thanks to @SirGregg for pointing me in in the right direction.
The first thing I did was add the CDATA block to my string array XML file like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <string-array name="payment_list">
    <item><![CDATA[<font color="#00ff00">Transaction Type: </font>]]>Pay Cash, Meet Up</item>
    <item><![CDATA[<font color="#00ff00">Transaction Type: </font>]]>Credit Card, Meet Up</item>
    <item><![CDATA[<font color="#00ff00">Transaction Type: </font>]]>Credit Card, Ship to Me</item>
  </string-array>
</resources>
```

Then, I went back to the code for adding the spinner and I changed it to:

```
final Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) popupView.findViewById(R.id.transaction_spinner);
String[] array = getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.payment_list);
Spanned[] spannedStrings = new Spanned[3];
for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
                spannedStrings[i] = Html.fromHtml(array[i]);
            }
spinner1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(getActivity(), R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,spannedStrings));
```