# Passing dynamic string resource to "setText()"

Tags: android

I am trying to make a dynamic string and converting a hardcoded string which has been passed to setText() function . However it doesn't seem to accept it .
Here is what I have tried :

Original code :

```
 device.name.setText("Mac :" + data.macAddress);
```

Strings.xml declaration :

```
<string name="mac">Mac :</string>
```

New code :

```
device.name.setText(R.string.mac + data.macAddress);
```

Code snippet :

```
   public class DeviceAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Device> {
    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;

    private final Device.IDeviceItem mListener;
    private final TextView mEmpty;

    public Vector<DeviceData> mDeviceData;

    public DeviceAdapter(Context context, TextView emptyView, Device.IDeviceItem listener) {
        mEmpty = emptyView;
        mListener = listener;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public Device onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int position) {
        return new Device(mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_device, parent, false), mListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(Device device, int position) {
        DeviceData data = mDeviceData.elementAt(position);

        device.position = position;
        device.deviceId = data.deviceId;

        device.name.setText("Mac :" + data.macAddress);   // check this
        if (data.temperature == null) {
            device.temperature.setText(R.string.temp_notset);
        }else device.temperature.setText("Temperature set to " + data.temperature + "\u00B0" +" celsius.");

        if (data.powerState) {
            device.btnPower.setImageResource(R.drawable.power_off);

            if (!data.startState) {
                device.status.setText(R.string.pon_running);
                device.btnStart.setImageResource(R.drawable.start_off);
            } else {
                device.status.setText(R.string.pon_stop);
                device.btnStart.setImageResource(R.drawable.start_on);
            }

        } else {
            device.btnPower.setImageResource(R.drawable.power_on);
            device.status.setText(R.string.poff);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        int sz = mDeviceData.size();
        if (sz == 0) {
            mEmpty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            mEmpty.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        return sz;
    }

    public boolean hasDevice(DeviceData deviceData) {
        for (DeviceData device : mDeviceData) {
            if (device.deviceId.equalsIgnoreCase(deviceData.deviceId) && device.boxid.equalsIgnoreCase(deviceData.boxid))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

So when I have hard-coded string : It displays the right value , However when changed dynamically it gets converted to an integer number "213136187044" . What am I doing wrong ? I am unable to post screenshots since my reputation is below 10 .

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML in string resource?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667319/html-in-string-resource)

Comment: First you should provide code properly then asked question.

Comment: @MD : You shouldn't down-vote new users and discourage them . Points going down put more restrictions on people to find help . I would have simply appreciated if you would have left me an advice instead of down-voting

Comment: @Dexter Ya that is fine. but you should take a look [How to ask?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) at least once becoz every day there are `>1000` new biee came in SO and if they asked `>100000` questions with No sense. So it's better to [Check this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @MD : My question did make perfect sense even without that code snippet ... I posted all details as per SO . What is problem , what I did try , Where I am getting the error. SO asks users to be specific to the problem .

Comment: @Dexter You think about that. `-3 down votes` proof that your question missed some useful information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

Create a global variable like:

```
private String name;
```

then in "onCreateViewHolder" write like this:

```
name= parent.getResources().getString(R.string.mac);
```

now, in "onBindViewHolder" write like this:

```
device.name.setText(name + data.macAddress);
```

Comment: Thanks again . Unfortunately device.getResources() is not available :(

Comment: Hi , same problem , parent.getResources() is not available

Comment: you are writing that code inside "onCreateViewHolder" before return statement method?

Comment: Yes I am writing it at the top below : 
    private final TextView mEmpty;

Comment: @Override
    public Device onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int position) {
        name = parent.getResources().getString(R.string.mac);
        return new Device(mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_device, parent, false), mListener);
    }  like this?

Comment: @Anand Singh I may have a similar problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43531900/android-how-to-fix-recyclerview-onbindviewholder.  I would appreciate any thoughts or ideas on how to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this

```
device.name.setText(data.macAddress + "");
```

or

```
device.status.setText(R.string.poff + "");
```

Comment: I want to have the string "Mac : " dynamically changed to whatever value I put in  strings.xml . However like I said it is instead giving me an integer value