# Android - html in strings.xml and getString()

Tags: android, html, xml, string

I have many strings like this:

```
<string name="exponent_key">x<sup><small>y</small></sup></string>
```

And when I set the text of a TextView, in an xml layout file, the result is a correctly superscripted 'y'.

However if i use `getString()` (or event try to retrieve the text, from the TextView mentioned above, using `.getText()`) and then use `setText()` to apply the changes, the 'y' gets changed back into normal text (so the result is just 'xy').

Is it possible to work around this? I was hoping that the html code is retained in the string so that i can use a `.replace()` to swap x and y with actual numbers later on, so that it would look like the real maths format. There are many operator strings like this so it will be difficult to manually re-add the html for each one.

Just in case you want to see my program: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62863300/Random/ScientificCalculator.zip

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML in string resource?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667319/html-in-string-resource)

Comment: Ah yes! I passed that post off after reading the first answer. So basically I don't convert the text to string ever? Leave as char sequence?

Answer (score 3):

> However if i use getString() (or event try to retrieve the text, from
>   the TextView mentioned above, using .getText()) and then use setText()
>   to apply the changes, the 'y' gets changed back into normal text (so
>   the result is just 'xy').

if you are using `getResources().getString()`, then you have to pass the result of `Html.fromHtml` to `setText()`. `TextView.getText()` returns a [CharSequence](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/CharSequence.html) which is superclass for `String` and `Spannable` (among the others). If you assign the return value of getString to  a `CharSequence`, without calling `toString()`, and then pass it back to `setText` it will maintain its style

Comment: I'll see what I can do about leaving the operator as a CharSequence. Edit: How do I replace "y" with "some stuff"?

Comment: Should I ask a separate question for that?

Comment: I will ask a separate question. I can't seem to find anything.