# What is the difference between getString() and getText()?

Tags: android, html

I tried using `getString()` to get a string from my `string.xml`
However. I just found the `getText()` method can fetch HTML tags from my resources!

Say:

```
<string name="mySTring"><b><i>Hello Guys</i></b></string>
```

it surprised me, because I had to use `Html.fromHtml()` to fetch the HTML tags - which is deprecated.

Which is the difference between the two methods?
Is there any advantage or disadvantage?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

From the doc,

For `Resources.getString()`:

> Return the string value associated with a particular resource ID.  It
>   will be stripped of any styled text information.

For `Resources.getText()`:

> Return the string value associated with a particular resource ID. The
>   returned object will be a String if this is a plain string; it will be
>   some other type of CharSequence if it is styled.

*[Note that `Context.getText()` and `Context.getString()` internally calls the methods from `Resources`.]*

The doc says that `getText()` retains the styling while the `getString()` not. But you can use either one to get the string resource with HTML tags from `strings.xml`, but the way is different.

**Using Resources.getText():**

`strings.xml`:

```
<string name="styled_text">Hello, <b>World</b>!</string>
```

You can just call `getText()` *(note that it returns a `CharSequence` not a `String`, so it has the styling properties)* and set the text to `TextView`. No need for `Html.fromHtml()`.

```
mTextView.setText(getText(R.string.styled_text));
```

But the [doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html) says only a limited HTML tags, such as `<b>, <i>, <u>` are supported by this method. The [source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/android-4.2.2_r1/core/java/android/content/res/StringBlock.java#L161) seems to suggest it supports more than that: `<b>, <i>, <u>, <big>, <small>, <sup>, <sub>, <strike>, <li>, <marquee>, <a>, <font> and <annotation>`

**Using Resources.getString():**

`strings.xml`:

```
<string name="styled_text"><![CDATA[Hello, <b>World</b>!]></string>
```

You have to surround your string in a `CDATA` block and calling `getString` will return the string with HTML tags. Here you have to use `Html.fromHtml()`.

```
mTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml( getString(R.string.styled_text)));
```

`Html.fromHtml()` is deprecated in favor of a new method with `flags` parameter. So use it like this:

```
HtmlCompat.fromHtml(getString(R.string.styled_text))
```

Implementation of the util method `HtmlCompat.fromHtml`:

```
public class HtmlCompat {

    public static CharSequence fromHtml(String source) {

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {

            //noinspection deprecation
            return Html.fromHtml(source);

        } else {

            return Html.fromHtml(source, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks clear explanation , so what is difference between Html.fromHtml and getText why the first one is deprecated and the other not ?

Comment: As mentioned in the answer itself, `getText` does not support all the HTML tags whereas `Html.fromHtml` does. And `getText` only works to get string from `strings.xml`. Html.fromHtml can be used for any string, for instance string from a Json response. `Html.fromHtml` has been deprecated and another similar method has been introduced with flags parameter.

Comment: thanks for your feedback , what if i want to use Html.fromHtml method in older API? the new similar method has been introduced for newer API. so there is no other way to approach?

Comment: None that I know of. You have to check the version and use different methods based on the version. Like the `HtmlCompat`, I have posted in the answer.

Comment: `<![CDATA[` must be closed with `]]>` not `]>`

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#String) there is practically no difference other than

```
You can use either getString(int) or getText(int) to retrieve a string. 
getText(int) will retain any rich text styling applied to the string.
```

So you would use getText for any localized resources for dealing with different language conversions for example but if you are just dealing with a string it literally doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

The way getString() implemented is to turn the data as string format ex 
"100" which take 100 as a string not an integer, The html tag is ignored as the method itself strip any tags. For getText method will capture all the TextView data or input from EditText. It's all about how you want to achieve yours program input and output handling with the right method.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit***

You can use either `getString(int)` or `getText(int)` to retrieve a string. `getText(int)` retains any rich text styling applied to the string

**Some Differences.....** according to the [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html)

```
getString(int id, Object... formatArgs)
```

> Return the string value associated with a particular resource ID,
>   substituting the format arguments as defined in Formatter and
>   format(String, Object...). **It will be stripped of any styled text
>   information.**

```
 getString(int id)
```

> Return the string value associated with a particular resource ID. **It
>   will be stripped of any styled text information.**

```
getText(int id, CharSequence def)
```

> Return the string value associated with a particular resource ID.

```
 getText(int id)
```

> Return the string value associated with a particular resource ID.
>   **The returned object will be a String if this is a plain string; it
>   will be some other type of CharSequence if it is styled.**

Comment: no, the current implementation of `Resources#getText()` return either `java.lang.String` if there are no html tags and `android.text.SpannedString` if you have them (like `this is some <b>bold</b> text` for example)

Comment: `SpannedString` is not `Editable`

Comment: Any edits to the answer is appreciated , will be useful for future users . thanks.

Comment: so i assume you verified that `Resources#getText()` returns `Editable` object? what API level did you run in on?

Comment: ok you maybe didnt notice we are talking about `Resources#getString` vs `Resources#getText`, not about `TextView#getText`

Comment: OK now I understand whats the problem , I read only the header of the question .. Sorry for distracting ......