# Inconsistencies when comparing CharSequence to String

Tags: android, string-comparison

I have the following code in my app:

```
if (mEnterPhoneNumberButton.getText().equals(getString(R.string.enter_phone_number_default_text))) {
                        showEnterPhoneNumberAlertDialog();
   }
```

This code produces the intended result for every device I've tested it on except for one (a Huawei P8 Lite running Android 5.0). For this one device, I need to add toString() to convert the CharSequence to a String. Otherwise the comparison returns false when it should be true:

```
if (mEnterPhoneNumberButton.getText().toString().equals(getString(R.string.enter_phone_number_default_text))) {
                        showEnterPhoneNumberAlertDialog();
   }
```

The above code works on every device. I understand that this is the proper way to do things, since a CharSequence isn't necessarily a String. But why the discrepancy based on device? Is this some customization/optimization put in by Huawei?

Comment: If you're comparing a CharSequence with a string in the resources, you can try to use getText method instead of getString. Also, take a look at this great answer that explains the differences between getString and getText (String vs CharSequence): https://stackoverflow.com/a/45648349/323149

Comment: @JaviMollá Good to know, but my string resource doesn't use any styling.

Comment: Maybe Huawei applies some styling to the button, I don't know