# How to predefine text features before using getString for recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, textview

I predefined some features in the string.xml file before I called the strings the recyclerView. But for some reason the size, format of the text is ignored, only the break line works.

Here is a picture of this:
[image]

Here's the predefined texts in `strings.xml`:

```
<string name="Use_your_voice_to_make_Money"><font size="17">Use your voice to make Money</font>
        \n<font size="13">Can you speak? This one might be for you – In a nutshell, you\'re paid to lend your voice to a project in need of a voice…</font>
    </string>
```

As you can see I literally specified the text size but it doesn't work. Please why is this??

And Here's the custom_list_view (for the recycler view)

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="425dp">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="370dp"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"
        app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            ....

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here's the layout of the fragment which holds the recyclerview:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.ways.WaysFragment">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:listitem="@layout/custom_ways_item" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Thanks for your help in advance.. I'm more than happy to provide any information needed. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm not sure what your code looks like, but you need to use `getText()` instead of `getString()` to preserve the formatting. https://stackoverflow.com/q/45647928

Comment: @MikeM. I just tried doing this, and I got an mismtach error, since I needed to add ".toString" ... Then I wrapped an arrayOf, of the getText in another arryOf but my app crashes anytime I go to the screen with this recyclerview.

Comment: `String`s do not have formatting. Calling `toString()` on the `getText()` return defeats the purpose, as it essentially strips all of that formatting. Beyond that, I don't really understand what you mean. If you'd like assistance in fixing a crash, you'll need to provide a [mcve] and the stack trace.