# Databinding remove html tags from string

Tags: android, data-binding

I want to use simply  tags from xml resourced String in databing.

```
public class StringUtils {
    public static String text(String a) {
        return a;
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@{StringUtils.text(@string/underlined_text)}" />
```

String :

```
    <string name="underlined_text">This is a <u>underlined</u> text.</string>
```

In the end when i debugging text method i realized that < u > tag is removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try and use HTML escape codes:

`<string name="underlined_text">This is a &lt;u&gt;underlined&lt;/u&gt; text.</string>`

I'd also question whether databinding is really required here - you can just use `android:text="@string/underlined_text"`

**Edit:** Also came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7641177/1219389) which could be of use to you

Answer (score 2):

It was never there in the first place, most likely.

In a string resource, recognized inline HTML elements, like `<u>`, are interpreted as part of the resource. If you call `getString()`, those HTML elements get stripped out. If you call `getText()` on a `Resources`, you get a `CharSequence` that contains the markup (e.g., `UnderlineSpan`).

Since you are using `String` everywhere, your HTML elements will get ignored.

I am not quite certain why you are setting up databinding this way. If you use:

```
android:text="@string/underlined_text"
```

you would get what you want, and faster. After all, `StringUtils` is doing nothing.

But, if you are really sure that you want to use data binding:

- Call `getText()` on a `Resources` with your string resource ID
- Pass that `CharSequence` around to get to your data binding expression

Alternatively, you could wrap the content of your string resource in `CDATA`, to keep the raw HTML intact. At some point, though, you would need to use `Html.fromHtml()` or something similar to get the `CharSequence` with the formatting applied.

Answer (score 1):

To use html tags in the string resource in databinding:

String:

```
<string name="underlined_text">This is a &lt;u>underlined&lt;/u> text.</string>
```

Layout:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <import type="android.text.Html" />
    </data>

    <your_root_view>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{Html.fromHtml(@string/underlined_text)}" />
    </your_root_view>
</layout>
```

Tested this method in **Android Studio 4.1.3**

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
android:text="@string/underlined_text"
```

You can change the defined string like this to keep the Spanned String:

```
<string name="underlined_text">This is a &lt;u&gt;underlined&lt;/u&gt; text.</string>
```