# Android studio display html in webview

Tags: html, android-studio, webview

I tried to display html that contains tables and characters,

At first Android studio didnt get the chars ("The entity ... was referenced, but not declared" error), so I replaced the html entity with the html code of each char and run the app.

Now it just shows me the contents of the tables in text form and without the tables.

**My Java code:**

```
package com.example.alpha3;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.Spanned;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class Summary extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView theSheet;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_summary);

        // get our html content
        String htmlAsString = getString(R.string.html);
        Spanned htmlAsSpanned = Html.fromHtml(htmlAsString); // used by TextView

        theSheet = findViewById(R.id.theSheet);
        theSheet.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, htmlAsString, "text/html", "charset=utf-8", null);
    }
}
```

**My strings.xml code:**

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">alpha3</string>
    <string name="name_of_the_competition">Name of the competition</string>
    <string name="city">City</string>
    <string-array name="roles">
        <item>Player</item>
        <item>Official</item>
        <item>Referee</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="officials">
        <item>C</item>
        <item>AC</item>
        <item>M</item>
        <item>T</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="positions">
        <item>I</item>
        <item>II</item>
        <item>III</item>
        <item>IV</item>
        <item>V</item>
        <item>VI</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="phase">
        <item>Pool/Phase</item>
        <item>Elim</item>
        <item>Seeding/Qual</item>
        <item>Final</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="category">
        <item>Category</item>
        <item>Senior</item>
        <item>Junior</item>
        <item>Youth</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="sanctions">
        <item>Delay</item>
        <item>Warning</item>
        <item>Penalty</item>
        <item>Expulsion</item>
        <item>Disqualification</item>
    </string-array>


    <string name="html">
       <table style="width: 555px; height: 50px;"><caption>
<h2>TEAMS</h2>
</caption>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="width: 50px; height: 25px;" colspan="2">&#160;Asa Ben-Gurion</td>
<td style="height: 25px; width: 50px;" colspan="2">&#160;Maccabi Tel-Aviv</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 25px; height: 25px; text-align: center;">&#160;2</td>
<td style="height: 25px;">&#160;Sharon Danieli</td>
<td style="height: 25px; width: 25px; text-align: center;">&#160;3</td>
<td style="height: 25px;">&#160;Sharon Danieli</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 25px; height: 25px; text-align: center;">3&#160;</td>
<td style="height: 25px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="height: 25px; width: 25px; text-align: center;">5&#160;</td>
<td style="height: 25px;">&#160;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 25px; height: 25px; text-align: center;">5</td>
<td style="height: 25px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="height: 25px; width: 25px; text-align: center;">6&#160;</td>
<td style="height: 25px;">&#160;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 25px; height: 25px; text-align: center;">7&#160;</td>
<td style="height: 25px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="height: 25px; width: 25px; text-align: center;">8&#160;</td>
<td style="height: 25px;">&#160;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 25px; height: 25px; text-align: center;">9&#160;</td>
<td style="height: 25px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="height: 25px; width: 25px; text-align: center;">10&#160;</td>
<td style="height: 25px;">&#160;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 25px; height: 25px; text-align: center;">11&#160;</td>
<td style="height: 25px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="height: 25px; width: 25px; text-align: center;">12&#160;</td>
<td style="height: 25px;">&#160;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 25px; height: 25px; text-align: center;">12&#160;</td>
<td style="height: 25px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="height: 25px; width: 25px; text-align: center;">15&#160;</td>
<td style="height: 25px;">&#160;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 25px; height: 25px; text-align: center;">18&#160;</td>
<td style="height: 25px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="height: 25px; width: 25px; text-align: center;">17&#160;</td>
<td style="height: 25px;">&#160;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 25px; height: 25px; text-align: center;">&#160;</td>
<td style="height: 25px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="height: 25px; width: 25px; text-align: center;">20&#160;</td>
<td style="height: 25px;">&#160;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 25px; height: 25px; text-align: center;">&#160;</td>
<td style="height: 25px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="height: 25px; width: 25px; text-align: center;">&#160;</td>
<td style="height: 25px;">&#160;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 25px; height: 25px; text-align: center;">&#160;</td>
<td style="height: 25px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="height: 25px; width: 25px; text-align: center;">&#160;</td>
<td style="height: 25px;">&#160;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 25px; height: 25px; text-align: center;">&#160;</td>
<td style="height: 25px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="height: 25px; width: 25px; text-align: center;">&#160;</td>
<td style="height: 25px;">&#160;</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table style="width: 555px; height: 25px;"><caption><strong>Officials</strong></caption>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 50px; text-align: center;">C</td>
<td>&#160;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 50px; text-align: center;">AC1;</td>
<td>&#160;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 50px; text-align: center;">AC2;</td>
<td>&#160;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 50px; text-align: center;">T</td>
<td>&#160;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 50px; text-align: center;">M</td>
<td>&#160;</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table style="width: 555px; height: 25px;"><caption><strong>Signatures</strong></caption>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="height: 50px; width: 100px;">Team Captain</td>
<td style="height: 50px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="height: 50px; width: 100px;">Team Captain</td>
<td style="height: 50px;">&#160;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="height: 50px; width: 100px;">Coach</td>
<td style="height: 50px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="height: 50px; width: 100px;">Coach</td>
<td style="height: 50px;">&#160;</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p>&#160;</p>
<h2>SET 1</h2>
<p>19:31-20:20</p>
<table style="width: 1000px; height: 25px;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="width: 150px;">Asa Ben-Gurion</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">1</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">2</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">3</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">4</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">5</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 150px;">Maccabi Tel-Aviv</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">1</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">2</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">3</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&#160;</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p>&#160;</p>
<table style="width: 552px; height: 25px;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td colspan="6">Asa Ben-Gurion</td>
<td colspan="6">Maccabi Tel-Aviv</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;" colspan="12"><strong>Starting Players</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 46px; text-align: center;">I</td>
<td style="width: 46px; text-align: center;">II</td>
<td style="width: 46px; text-align: center;">III</td>
<td style="width: 46px; text-align: center;">IV</td>
<td style="width: 46px; text-align: center;">V</td>
<td style="width: 46px; text-align: center;">VI</td>
<td style="width: 46px; text-align: center;">I</td>
<td style="width: 46px; text-align: center;">II</td>
<td style="width: 46px; text-align: center;">III</td>
<td style="width: 46px; text-align: center;">IV</td>
<td style="width: 46px; text-align: center;">V</td>
<td style="width: 46px; text-align: center;">VI</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;">7</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">13</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">2</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">3</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">11</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">5</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">6</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">5</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">15</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">8</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">3</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">17</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;" colspan="12"><strong>Substitutes</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">1) 12&#8645;2</td>
<td colspan="2">2) 18&#8645;7</td>
<td colspan="2">3)</td>
<td colspan="2">1) 12&#8645;17</td>
<td colspan="2">2) 20&#8645;8</td>
<td colspan="2">3) 10&#8645;;5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">4)</td>
<td colspan="2">5)</td>
<td colspan="2">6)</td>
<td colspan="2">4) 5&#8645;10</td>
<td colspan="2">5)</td>
<td colspan="2">6)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;" colspan="12"><strong>Time outs</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;" colspan="3">5:9</td>
<td style="text-align: center;" colspan="3">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center;" colspan="3">10:12</td>
<td style="text-align: center;" colspan="3">11:14</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;" colspan="12"><strong>Sanctions</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;" colspan="3">D</td>
<td style="text-align: center;" colspan="3">20:14</td>
<td style="text-align: center;" colspan="3">W&#160;&#8594; C</td>
<td style="text-align: center;" colspan="3">7:14</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;" colspan="3">W&#160;&#8594; 13</td>
<td style="text-align: center;" colspan="3">21:15</td>
<td style="text-align: center;" colspan="3">P&#160;&#8594; 15</td>
<td style="text-align: center;" colspan="3">9:17</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;" colspan="3">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center;" colspan="3">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center;" colspan="3">E&#160;&#8594; C</td>
<td style="text-align: center;" colspan="3">9:17</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;" colspan="3">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center;" colspan="3">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center;" colspan="3">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center;" colspan="3">&#160;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;" colspan="3">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center;" colspan="3">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center;" colspan="3">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center;" colspan="3">&#160;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;" colspan="3">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center;" colspan="3">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center;" colspan="3">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center;" colspan="3">&#160;</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p>&#160;</p>
<table style="width: 550px; height: 25px;"><caption>
<h2 style="text-align: center;">RESULTS</h2>
</caption>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: left; width: 275px;">Asa Ben-Gurion</td>
<td style="width: 275px; text-align: left;">Maccabi Tel-Aviv</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table style="width: 550px; height: 25px;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;"><strong>"T"</strong></td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><strong>S</strong></td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><strong>W</strong></td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><strong>P</strong></td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><strong>Set Duration</strong></td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><strong>P</strong></td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><strong>W</strong></td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><strong>S</strong></td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><strong>"T"</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 56px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 56px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 56px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 56px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 56px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 56px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 56px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 56px;">&#160;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 56px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 56px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 56px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 56px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 56px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 56px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 56px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 56px;">&#160;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 56px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 56px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 56px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 56px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 56px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 56px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 56px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 56px;">&#160;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 56px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 56px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 56px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 56px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 56px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 56px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 56px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 56px;">&#160;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 56px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 56px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 56px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 56px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 56px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 56px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 56px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 56px;">&#160;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 56px;" colspan="9"><strong>Total</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 56px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 56px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 56px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 56px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 56px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 56px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 56px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 56px;">&#160;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 56px;" colspan="3"><strong>Match Starting Time</strong></td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 56px;" colspan="3"><strong>Match Ending Time</strong></td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 56px;" colspan="3"><strong>Total Match Duration</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 56px;" colspan="3">19:01</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 56px;" colspan="3">21:35</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 56px;" colspan="3">02:34</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 56px;" colspan="3"><strong>WINNER</strong></td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 56px;" colspan="3">Asa Ben-Gurion</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 56px;" colspan="3">3:1</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p>&#160;</p>
<table style="width: 450px; height: 25px;"><caption>
<h2 style="text-align: center;">SANCTIONS</h2>
</caption>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 25px;"><strong>W</strong></td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 25px;"><strong>P</strong></td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 25px;"><strong>E</strong></td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 25px;"><strong>D</strong></td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><strong>Team</strong></td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 25px;"><strong>SET</strong></td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 50px;"><strong>SCORE</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 25px;">C</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 25px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 25px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 25px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">Maccabi tel-aviv</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 25px;">1</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 50px;">7:14</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 25px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 25px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 25px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 25px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 25px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 50px;">&#160;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 25px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 25px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 25px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 25px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 25px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 50px;">&#160;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 25px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 25px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 25px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 25px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 25px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 50px;">&#160;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 25px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 25px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 25px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 25px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 25px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 50px;">&#160;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 25px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 25px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 25px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 25px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 25px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 50px;">&#160;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 25px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 25px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 25px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 25px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 25px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 50px;">&#160;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 25px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 25px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 25px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 25px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 25px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 50px;">&#160;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 25px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 25px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 25px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 25px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 25px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 50px;">&#160;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 25px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 25px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 25px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 25px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 25px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 50px;">&#160;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 25px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 25px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 25px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 25px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 25px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 50px;">&#160;</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p>&#160;</p>
<table style="width: 552px; height: 25px;"><caption>
<h2 style="text-align: center;">APPROVAL</h2>
</caption>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 80px;"><strong>Referees</strong></td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 200px;"><strong>Name</strong></td>
<td style="width: 60px; text-align: center;"><strong>Country</strong></td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><strong>Signature</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 80px; text-align: center; height: 50px;">1st</td>
<td style="width: 200px; height: 50px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 60px; height: 50px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="height: 50px;">&#160;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 80px; text-align: center; height: 50px;">2nd</td>
<td style="width: 200px; height: 50px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 60px; height: 50px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="height: 50px;">&#160;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 80px; text-align: center; height: 50px;">Scorer</td>
<td style="width: 200px; height: 50px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="width: 60px; height: 50px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="height: 50px;">&#160;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 80px; text-align: center; height: 50px;">Assistant Scorer</td>
<td style="height: 50px; width: 200px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="height: 50px; width: 60px;">&#160;</td>
<td style="height: 50px;">&#160;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 80px; text-align: center; height: 25px;" colspan="4"><strong>Line Judges</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 80px; text-align: center; height: 25px;" colspan="4">&#160;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 80px; text-align: center; height: 25px;" colspan="4">&#160;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 80px; text-align: center; height: 25px;" colspan="4">&#160;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 80px; text-align: center; height: 25px;" colspan="4">&#160;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 80px; text-align: center; height: 25px;" colspan="4">&#160;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 80px; text-align: center; height: 25px;" colspan="4"><strong>Team Captains</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 80px; height: 50px; text-align: left;" colspan="3">Asa Ben-Gurion</td>
<td style="height: 50px;">&#160;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 80px; height: 50px; text-align: left;" colspan="3">Maccabi Tel-Aviv</td>
<td style="height: 50px;">&#160;</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p>&#160;</p>
<h2>REMARKS<br /><br /><br /><br /></h2>
<p>&#160;</p>
    </string>
</resources>
```

What can I do to make the file display as planned?
Thanks to responders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your string definition is wrong. In the end you want to embed html into the `strings.xml` file.
This can be done by wrapping the xml in the `<![CDATA[ .. ]]>` tag.

See [HTML in string resource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667319/html-in-string-resource) for more details.