# Covert html to string in android

Tags: java, android, html

I have a html tag

```
 <html><body>You scored <b>192</b> points.</body></html>
```

I want to convert the html to string for this i use the code

```
String ni=  Html.fromHtml((String) "<html><body>You scored <b>192</b> points.</body</html>").toString();
```

and i got the out put as

> You scored 192 points.

But i want the out put as

> You scored **192** points.

That is 192 should be bold. I want to print this result using a bluetooth printer. so can't use webview for view that.So is there any API to convert the HTML to String without change its format.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display HTML Formatted String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478503/display-html-formatted-string)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that you're assigning the return-value of the [`Html.fromHtml()`-method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml%28java.lang.String%29) to a `String`-object. The method returns a [`Spanned`-object](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spanned.html), which is able to hold information like text-markup. By assigning it to a String, the object "forgets" these information.

This is possible, because the `Spanned`-interface implements the [`CharSequence`-interface](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/CharSequence.html) (therefor *is* a char-sequence) and [`String` implements `CharSequence`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html).

This should however work:

```
Spanned ni = Html.fromHtml((String) "<html><body>You scored <b>192</b> points.</body</html>").toString();
```

Comment: i got the error use the above code...

Comment: @Nithinlal I have no idea what you're saying.

Answer (score 0):

In case your are trying to show that in TextView, you can use below code,

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("YOUR HTML STRING"), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Give it a try